# Expression Error When Returning Value to Record

Tags: json, jwt, powerbi, token, powerquery

I am attempting to make this POST request to retrieve a JWT Token to be stored as a record in a table. It does retrieve the token. However, I am receiving the error "Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIs..." to type Record. Type=[Type]". Thoughts on where I am going wrong here?

```
let
    url = "https://sapif.callminer.net/security/getToken", 
    body = "{""Username"": ""xxxxx"", ""Password"": ""xxxx"", ""ApiKey"": ""xxxxxx""}",
    Parsed_JSON = Json.Document(body),
    BuildQueryString = Uri.BuildQueryString(Parsed_JSON),
    token = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json; charset=utf-8"], Content = Text.ToBinary(body) ] )),
#"Converted in table" = Record.ToTable(token)
in
#"Converted in table"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:
`let url = "https://sapif.callminer.net/security/getToken",  body = "{""Username"": ""svc-piautomation@alegeus.com"", ""Password"": ""3tmvF7c_U=ZCHywW"", ""ApiKey"": ""alegeus""}", Parsed_JSON = Json.Document(body), BuildQueryString = Uri.BuildQueryString(Parsed_JSON), token = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json; charset=utf-8"], Content = Text.ToBinary(body) ] )), #"Converted in table" = Record.ToTable([Token = token]) in #"Converted in table"`

Comment: I don't understand this answer, and I'm hoping you can help. `body` is defined early and then it is converted to JSON and built into a query string as `BuildQueryString`. But `BuildQueryString` isn't used in your `Web.Contents` request -- `body` is.  But `body` hasn't been modified.  Did you use `body` or `BuildQueryString` in the request?